# Scroll to top not working after ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, scroll

Sorry for the long explanation: I have not been a coder for some years now, and time to time I return to do some projects because of budget issues. I am currently running this site for educational purposes, that informs the community about the benefits of animal-humans interactions. We do much some entertainment posts, but most are written by veterinary doctors. Recently I add to organize the site posts into categories i.e dog cats vaccines, etc. Since the site is not very optimised and the server is kind of slow I made a lateral menu calling post via Ajax.
The problem I am facing is that despite my efforts of placing a:

- window.scrollTo(0, 0);

  2. $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
  3. $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
  4. A settimeout function to deal with the AJAX loading

Nothing works. I am probably being dense about this but it is taking me days to figure out what am not seeing. And is rendering the site not very functional.
The site is www.guiadocao.com the menu on the site when you click does not go up after loading the contents. I am not asking anyone to debug this but honestly i ran all the option available. So just appreciate if a fresh pair of eyes could shed new light into this.

Regards to all,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the code you are using is doing exactly what you are asking it to. The problem is, the body of the page fits on the height and nothing more, so there's no scrolling. You should try to scroll on the element with the `id` equal to `main` (or the element containing the articles if I'm wrong about the id).

Comment: `  $('html, body').animate({
                 scrollTop: $("#main").offset().top
               }, 2000);       

                  }  ` I have tried this but still nothing.

Comment: `$('#main').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');` Tested in the console and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a success callback scrollTop function to your AJAX request.

```
var call = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/path/",
    success: $(window).scrollTop(0)
});
```